# emacs: search for part of a filename

Tags: emacs

In eclipse (with the emacs keys) i hit ctrl-x-ctrl-f and it searches for filenames containing the word I type. what is the equivalent emacs feature emacs feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try [find-file-in-project](http://github.com/bbatsov/find-file-in-project) + [ido-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc1). Alternative you can try the newer and more feature complete project [projectile](http://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).

Comment: ido like ido! this made my day!

Answer (score 2):

You can autocomplete filenames in the current directory with TAB, but it sounds a little like you are wanting some kind of project management (to find all matching files belonging to a pre-defined project, not just in the current directory).

Is that the case? (If not, which files do you want to search?)

`M-x find-dired` is useful for running arbitrary find commands from the current (or specified) directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press Tab to display list of files matching your search, it's like auto-completion in bash.

Edit: of course after pressing ctrl-x ctrl-f

Comment: That would only search one directory.

Answer (score 0):

This might help a little: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TextMate

Answer (score 0):

You probably want ido mode with flex matching:

```
(ido-mode t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

Comment: That sounds interesting, could you tell me more? links?

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages that let you type a substring to match during completion. Ido is one.

**Icicles** is another -- it also lets you match regexps or match using several varieties of fuzzy matching.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion

Most importantly, **Icicles** offers *progressive completion*. That means that you can combine more than one match pattern (they are ANDed). Coming up with simple match patterns is much easier than coming up with a single complex regexp to do all the work. And you can see the cumulative effect of each pattern.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion

What's more, you can subtract pattern matches: type another pattern, which gets ANDed with the current matches. Then hit <kbd>C-~</kbd> and you end up with the matches you had before the AND minus the ANDed result: the *complement* of the last pattern-match you added.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway